# Why router can use layer 4 infomation in emcp hash?

Tags: networking, network-programming, load-balancing, router

Router is layer 3 device, but it can use layer 4 info (like:dst.port, src.port, protocol) in ecmp hash function.
Why?

Answer (score 0):

Because it cheats and looks at that information. Nothing is stopping it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you want every packet in a given stream (defined by src addr, dst addr, src proto/port, dst proto/port) to take the same path so that these pkts arrive in order.  Otherwise the application might have issues trying to re-sort.  Different ECMP paths have different delays.